# Adding Quadrants to R Scatterplots, and lines pointing from plots to their respective labels

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

With ggplot2, can I add four quadrants. Basically just a line down the middle for the y and x axis (a plus sign)? I also wanted to see if i can have a lines pointing from the labels to their respective dots. The labeling overlap is getting problematic.

[image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/1eoolu.jpg]

```
data$Goal <- factor(data$Goal, levels = c("KPI", 
     "Strategic Support and Relationship Management", 
     "Sales and Marketing Support", 
      "Google AW Account Management and Product Support"))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = X, y = Y,  color = Goal)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red4", "purple4", "olivedrab")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Label), color = "black", 
      position = "jitter", hjust=0.6, vjust=1.1, size = 2.5) +
  labs(title = "PSAT", x = "Impact on Overall Satisfaction", y = "Higher Rating")
```

Comment: Have you tried the `directlabels` package to avoid text overlap at all?

Comment: what is that? and no...

Comment: As of 2016, use ggrepel to fix label overlap in ggplot2 charts. https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel

Answer (score 4):

Just doing the same thing (the quadrants part) and have used:

```
p<-ggplot(survey.df, aes(x=specificity, y=success)) +
  geom_point() +
  lims(x=c(1,10),y=c(1,10)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_fixed() +  
  geom_vline(xintercept = 5) + geom_hline(yintercept = 5) 
p
```

Giving
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for the lines pointing from the labels to their respective dots:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = X, y = Y,  color = Goal)) + 
   geom_point(size=3) + 
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red4", "purple4", "olivedrab")) +
   geom_text_repel(aes(label = Label), color = "black", size = 2.5) +
   labs(title = "PSAT", x = "Impact on Overall Satisfaction", y = "Higher Rating")
```